# PHP + Code igniter locale settings

Tags: php, locale

I have an application where I need to use

- Different languages (I already have this working perfectly)
- Different date formats currency formats (Still working on this).

I am guessing this has something to do with locale

- Is it possible to automatically determine locale? (<= php 5.2)
- If this is not possible, is there a list somewhere of all possible "locale"
- Is the preferred method for setting locale setlocale?
- Is it a bad idea to have both a language setting and a locale setting in an application?

Answer (score 0):

This might help.
setlocale(LC_ALL, $CI->config->item('language'));

It sets the locale to whatever language you are using.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at the [Language Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html). It seems to answer some of your questions.

Comment: Thanks but as stated in the question I got different languages working correctly. The problem I am having is different date formats.